# How can i set a color in header string in NPOI?

Tags: c#, npoi

I want to set a color for font and I used `IHeader` i have no idea how to set a color using `&K`. Please help and make a string to set a color to header font.

```
header.Right = "PRIVILEGED AND CONFIDENTIAL"+ "\r\n " + "ATTORNEY WORK-PRODUCT ";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors can be specified inline using

```
&K[RRGGBB]
```

with RRGGBB the hexadecimal color encoding, as you would use in (for example) HTML. Most color selection dialogs in drawing programs or [online](http://paletton.com/) will tell you the RRGGBB value of a color.

Example code:

```
IHeader header = sheet.Header;
header.Center = "This is a &K0000FFblue text";
```